Does git support applying patches (`.patch` files) to tree-ish?
I've got a server serving git repositories, bare, they can be pulled from and pushed to as normal.
For convenience, I'd like to support sending patches via a side channel and having those patches get applied to relevant branches by the server.
However as far as I can tell neither git am nor git apply support working with bare repositories, applying patches to tree-ish objects.
Obviously it's always possible to create a worktree or clone-with-working copy and apply patches to that, but that's a lot of FS churn, so I wanted to know if there's a way to do that built-in, without having to parse and apply patches "by hand" to individual blobs.

I'm not knowledgable with git enough to know for sure, but I don't see how you can without a worktree.

What does it even mean "apply patches to non-checked out blobs"? Git object database stores commits, trees and blobs; blobs are referenced from trees that are referenced from commits. When you "applying patches to non-checked out blobs" where are commits that reference the patched blobs?

@phd I don't know what that means because you're apparently inventing a quote. But a git tree is a directory, so a commit links to a tree representing an entire folder, whose blobs you can apply hunks to.

@evolutionxbox a patch is just instructions for modifying files. You can access that without a working copy, a git tree is a directory whose entries are either directories (other trees) or files (blobs), that's the same thing as a regular filesystem. For instance if you create a bare clone of https://github.com/git/git, you can git show HEAD:gitweb/static/js/blame_incremental.js and it'll give you the content of that file. Low-level commands of git allow creating, updating, and even merging trees without a working copy. So there's nothing outlandish about applying a patch to a tree to me.

@Masklinn You cannot apply patches to existing objects, tree or not tree. Git objects are immutable. Changing blobs changes their hashes (do you understand what "content-addressable filesystem" means in Git?), which changes tree hashes, which changes commit hash. In short — you have to create a new commit with new trees and patched blobs. And you have to decide to what branch you gonna add the new commit. So you you need to check out a commit from a branch, and you need a worktree for that.

@Masklinn thank you for explaining, but I must agree with phd.

@phd of course applying a patch to a tree would create a new tree, that is blatantly obvious, that is how git works. However no you don't have to "decide to what branch you gonna add the new commit", you can create commits which are not on branches, and you can create trees which are not linked to commits. I would suggest reading the documentation for the mktree and commit-tree commands. As well as the merge-tree command so that you can see that you can recursively merge trees without needing a working copy.

@evolutionxbox then I'm sorry for you, because he has no idea what he's talking about and it is just sad to see.

@torek I summon thee

How do you plan to handle conflicts when the patch does not apply cleanly?

An error and a rejection would be perfectly fine for my purposes, the patch can just be created anew and up to date.


Obviously it's always possible to create a worktree or clone-with-working copy and apply patches to that, but that's a lot of FS churn

Git has always been able to do minimum-checkout merge/apply, you never needed to do a full checkout for this.
If you're on a server in a bare clone and want to update HEAD,
$ git clone -ns . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
$ git read-tree HEAD
$ git apply -3 <the.patch

and apply will get only what it needs. You can then git commit-tree the tree git write-tree makes and push the resulting commit back to exactly where you want.
I did this with a Git patch I got off the mailing list, "[PATCH 1/6] refs: properly apply exclude patterns to namespaced refs", it took basically nothing. There's some extra shenanigans here to apply on a commit that hasn't yet been patched, you'll see:
[jthill@denisov jthill]$ cd git
/home/jthill/src/git
[jthill@denisov git]$ git pull
[…]
[jthill@denisov git]$ git tag fixit $(git log -1 --pretty=%H --grep 'properly apply exclude' --all)^
[jthill@denisov git]$ git clone -nsb fixit . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
Cloning into '/tmp/jthill/tmp.FywiM3hlPc'...
done.
[jthill@denisov tmp.FywiM3hlPc]$ git read-tree HEAD
[jthill@denisov tmp.FywiM3hlPc]$ wl-paste|sed s,\\r$,,|git apply --cached -3
Applied patch to 'refs.c' cleanly.
Applied patch to 'refs.h' cleanly.
Applied patch to 't/t5509-fetch-push-namespaces.sh' cleanly.
[jthill@denisov tmp.FywiM3hlPc]$ git commit -m-
[detached HEAD 1a94891ac0] -
 3 files changed, 41 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
[jthill@denisov tmp.FywiM3hlPc]$ du -sh .git .
672K    .git
4.0K    .
[jthill@denisov tmp.FywiM3hlPc]$


How do you explain the output of the du -sh .git .? Shouldn't . include the space needed by .git?

Oh, its a feature of du that it doesn't count stuff twice.
